# Caching issue with Centos forwarding DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos5

I installed a Forwarding DNS server on Centos 5.10  and it is resolving addresses e.g google.com. When I stopped named (service named stop) and tried to dig (dig @localhost A google.com) there was a failure to resolve the address. I checked and see the caching daemon nscd  is running.

Does this mean the server is not caching at all? How can I get it to cache?

**named.conf**

```
     options
   {
    // Those options should be used carefully because they disable port
    // randomization
// query-source    port 53; 
// query-source-v6 port 53;

// Put files that named is allowed to write in the data/ directory:
    listen-on port 53 {127.0.0.1; 10.0.0.4;};
    directory "/var/named"; // the default
    dump-file       "/var/named/chroot/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file     "/var/named/chroot/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file  "/var/named/chroot/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
   // allow-query {localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.0.0.0/8;};
    recursion yes;
    //allow-query  { localhost; 10.0.0.0/8;};
    allow-query     { localhost; any; };
    allow-query-cache    { localhost; any; };
    forward only;  
    forwarders {8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;};

    dnssec-enable yes;
    // dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    // bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    // managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
```

};
logging 
{

```
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
```

};
**

Answer (score 1):

DNS caching on Linux (via nscd) is traditionally disabled by default. Check /etc/nscd.conf if you want to enable it. Be warned, it might create more [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020027/dns-caching-in-linux) for you. I personally have never relied on it for DNS. If you want DNS resolution to keep working when/if Bind crashes, AND you still have network connectivity, it's better to just specify more servers in /etc/resolv.conf

The reason dig @127.0.0.1 fails to work is that it consults the DNS server directly through port 53. It does not use the [NSS](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Name-Service-Switch.html) functions.